# Cannot get the value from a class in C++?

Tags: c++

I just came from Java and Python world to C++ world, and faced a problem while trying to get the value from a public `const` function of a class.

I have a class as follows:

```
class CMDPoint
{
public:
    CMDPoint();
    CMDPoint(int nDimensions);
    virtual ~CMDPoint();
private:
    int m_nDimensions;      // the number of dimensions of a point
    float* m_coordinate;    // the coordinate of a point
public:
    const int GetNDimensions() const { return m_nDimensions; }
    const float GetCoordinate(int nth) const { return m_coordinate[nth]; }
    void SetCoordinate(int nth, float value) { m_coordinate[nth] = value; }
};
```

**Ultimately**, I wish to write **all** the `clusterPoint`s in `clusterPointArray` into the file. However, **now** I am just testing it with the **first** `clusterPoint` (thus, `GetCoordinate(0)`).

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("C:\\data\\test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
for (std::vector<CMDPoint> ::iterator it = clusterEntry->clusterPointArray.begin(); it   != clusterEntry->clusterPointArray.end(); ++it)
{
    outFile << ("%f", (*it).GetCoordinate(0)); // fails
    outFile << " ";
}
outFile << "\n";
outFile.close();
```

The problem is I only see the `" "` in the file. No coordinate has been written in. Did I do anything wrong while fetching the value from `const float GetCoordinate(int nth)`?

Comment: Just use `outFile << it->GetCoordinate(0);`. I also suggest adding bounds checking to `CMDPoint::GetCoordinate`, by using a `std::vector` instead of an array and subsequently using `m_coordinate.at(nth)`. Otherwise you'll probably run into segfaults if you are new to C++.

Comment: @MarcClaesen No, still the same. :/

Comment: Have you ensured the coordinate index has been set correctly?  i.e `m_coordinate[0]` actually has a value.  You do no error checking.

Comment: @Chemistpp even an uninitialized float would serialize to *some* number (or segfault if the array is a nullptr).

Comment: @Chemistpp I also tried GetCoordinate(1) still the same. Do you mean by this?

Comment: What is this? I've never seen it before. `outFile << ("%f", (*it).GetCoordinate(0)); // fails`

Comment: I seriously wonder where you get from that `outFile << ("%f", (*it).GetCoordinate(0));` will do remotely waht you want in c++...

Comment: Where do you allocate space for the array?

Comment: You don't need to return `const int` and `const float`. It's superfluous. You don't need to force your user to handle them as const.

Comment: What does "fails" even mean? Doesn't compile? Crash? Do the wrong thing?

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Well, have you tried just a standard `std::cout << m_coordinate[nth];` in your get function to ensure the value is correctly stored in the array?  However, Marc Claesen suggest this wouldn't be the problem cause, and he's probably right.  You'd throw an uninitialized variable usage if using visual studio or it would have some value or seg fault.

Comment: @SebastianRedl  compiles but does nothing

Comment: I think clusterEntry->clusterPointArray has no elements. You can check with the debugger is code actually goes inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

try to change this

```
outFile << ("%f", (*it).GetCoordinate(0)); // fails
```

to this:

```
outFile << (*it).GetCoordinate(0); // OK
```

Because the `("%f", (*it).GetCoordinate(0))` represents nothing , only a enumerations of expressions separated by `,` . It will not be evaluated into a pair of objects as in java is i think.

Edit:`("%f", (*it).GetCoordinate(0))` actually evaluates to the last element that is `(*it).GetCoordinate(0)` ( PlasmaHH comment ) so it should still print something. However if nothing is printed then the collection `clusterEntry->clusterPointArray` could be empty and the code inside the for loop might not be executed ever.

Hope this helps,
Razvan.

Comment: It will actually evalaute to the last one, just like `std::cout << (1,2,3)` will print out `3`

Comment: PlasmaHH 4 you were right about that, i was wondering how is that compiling , i have never used that.

Answer (score 0):

```
outFile << it->GetCoordinate(0);
```

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Then your m_coordinate does not point to a valid array.